# java images not loading correctly windows 10

Tags: java, image, javafx

This is how I am trying to load the images

```
String imagePath = "/hive/pions/images/pionimages/" + pionColor + "/" + pionType + ".png";

pionImageView.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath)));
```

[image]

My package structure looks like this so that cannot be the problem right? And the "/" should work in both linux as windows?
Thing is it is working on linux and mac but not on windows.

JAR file contents:

[image]

Comment: Your package structure (pions/images), doesn't seem to match your path String "images/pions/".

Comment: my bad sorry didn't show full picture

Comment: image updated. Could it be because i use the same name for 2 packages?

Comment: also I am trying to load the images from the Pion class so I do not need to do /pions/images/pions/... Doing /images/pions/... should be fine right?

Comment: I would try with the full path.

Comment: if you print out the imagepath, can you manually see the picture?

Comment: Yes, but in intellij it all works fine. But when creating the jar it only seems to work on linux and mac

Comment: you mean full path like src/game/pions/images/pions/... ?

Comment: src won't exit in the destination, I would try game/pions/images/pions/...

Comment: Still only works on mac and linux

Comment: Check where you're calling the image from, relatively. Try using the full path from root. Ensure that your images have been built into your resultant jar.

Comment: used full path from root I am 100% sure the jar is generated correctly as that is done by the professor

Comment: **Either** access a file by using `Paths.get(somePath).toUri().toURL().toExternalForm()` **or** use `getClass().getResource...` **but not both**.

Comment: Disregard the professor. Check the contents of the jar yourself. You're going to have to do this in the future anyway. If you check the path of the image inside the jar, it becomes trivial to know how to refer to it in your code. You then simply write it accordingly, rather than wasting time debugging blindly.

Comment: I don't get it my path seems correct right? See picture I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the Path class.  And do not use the File class.

The argument to Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream is not a file name;  it is a relative URL.  URLs *always* use forward slash (`/`) as the file separator, on all platforms.

When you execute Path.toString(), you are getting a file name appropriate for the platform on which you’re running.  Which means on Windows, the directories will be separated by `\`.  The result is a String which is not a valid argument to Class.getResourceAsStream.

Just skip using Path altogether:

```
String imagePath = "images/pions/" + pionColor + "/" + pionType + ".png";
```

Comment: even when doing that `String imagePath = "images/pionimages/" + pionColor + "/" + pionType + ".png";
        pionImageView.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath)));` I am getting the same results

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the path with a / so that it is relative to the JAR root; otherwise it will be relative to the class name.

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("image/foo")` will map to `com/example/packagename/image/foo`

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/foo"` will map to `image/foo`

Comment: still same for some reason. path now looks like this `String imagePath = "/game/pions/images/pionimages/" + pionColor + "/" + pionType + ".png";`

Comment: Is `/game/pions/` in the JAR or in the at the top of the CLASSPATH? If not that won't work. It's not a file name, it's a resource in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Joey there is no "pionimages" in screen above

Comment: I changed the name because i tought that using pions twice would cause problems

Comment: @Joey stop trying random strings. Look for the base of the CLASSPATH or the content of the JAR. Use the full prefix for the path of the JAR only, or the path to the right of the base of the CLASSPATH only. Don't put in any other file or folder names.

Comment: edited my post showing contents of JAR but my path seems correct

Comment: And when you used "/hive/pions/images/..." what happened?

Comment: When trying to load the JAR on linux or mac everything went fine. When trying to load the JAR in windows. Error inputstream cannot be null